# Abstract interface pattern

Tags: .net, design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design

Can any one provide explanation of Abstract interface pattern.

The book "N-Layered Domain-Oriented Architecture Guide with .NET 4.0" has reference of this pattern, but no explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it means having an interface, an abstract class that implements that interface and then several non-abstract classes that inherit from the abstract class. In C# code:

```
interface IFoo
{
    // interface members
}

abstract class FooBase : IFoo
{
    // implementation of IFoo and potentially some helper methods
    // some methods can be abstract, some virtual
}

class ConcreteFoo : FooBase
{
    // overrides abstract members of FooBase and potentially some virtual ones
}
```

The advantage of using this pattern is that it combines benefits of interfaces (flexibility) with benefits of abstract base classes (sharing implementation).

Comment: Guru, can you provide any reference ?  real time example is a great help.

Comment: The only reference I could find is https://staff.rockwood.k12.mo.us/hancockglenn/apcompsci/Documents/AbstractInterfacePattern.ppt

Answer (score 0):

Abstract Interface doesn't really exist in C#. In C++ you have the notion of a "pure abstract" class, in which all methods are abstract, hence it's an abstract class that only defines an interface.

In C# we have the 'interface' keyword instead, which does the exact same thing.

Comment: I am asking about architecture pattern not a language concept.

Comment: Yes, to which I answered it's an abstract class without any implementation.